# Access to foreach variable in closure

Tags: c#, .net

Имею следующий код:

```
foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo info in _comps)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SpeedLabel.Content += info.NetInterface.Description + " - " + info.IncomeSpeed + "kbps\n");
}
```

На что получаю предупреждение:

> Access to foreach variable in closure. May have different behaviour when compiled with different versions of compiler.

Какое "различное поведение" может произойти и в каких случаях?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите.

Цикл `foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo info in _comps)` может быть реализован так:

```
NetworkInterfaceInfo info;
using (var iterator = _comps.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        info = iterator.Current;
        // тело вашего цикла
    }
}
```

А может и так:

```
using (var iterator = _comps.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        NetworkInterfaceInfo info = iterator.Current;
        // тело вашего цикла
    }
}
```

В старых версиях использовался первый вариант. При этом если вы выполняете closure по `info` (то есть, запоминаете текущее значение `info` в `() => SpeedLabel.Content += info.NetInterface.Description...`), к моменту фактической отработки функции переменной `info` может быть уже присвоено другое значение, совсем не то, которое вы ожидали, потому что цикл при этом уже пробежал до конца.

Во втором случае у вас на каждую итерацию свежая переменная, и «изменения» `info` в цикле нет. При этом каждое замыкание общается со своим экземпляром `info`.

Это и есть то самое изменение поведения, о котором вас предупредил компилятор. Ваш код будет бежать по-разному с разными версиями языка.

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [*Closing over the loop variable considered harmful*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful),
- [*Closing over the loop variable, part two*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two).

Comment: *"Ваш код будет бежать по-разному с разными версиями .NET."* - не совсем так. От версии .NET ничего не зависит, поведение кода зависит от версии компилятора.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, хм, вы правы, обычно разные версии компилятора компилируют под «свою» версию .NET, но код, конечно, можно запустить и под другой версией. Исправлю ответ.

Answer (score 3):

В версиях C# до 5-й переменная цикла `foreach` создавалась вне цикла. Это значит, что после выхода из цикла `foreach` у лямбд будет захвачено последнее значение из перечисления. В C# 5 это поведение было изменено, и переменная создаётся внутри цикла.

Возьмём цикл:

```
var list = new List<Action>();
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 3))
    list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
list.ForEach(a => a());
```

В C# 4 код получится такой:

```
int i;
using (var it = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).GetEnumerator()) {
    while (it.MoveNext()) {
        i = it.Current;
        list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }
}
```

Будет выведено: `333`.

В C# 5 уже такой:

```
using (var it = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).GetEnumerator()) {
    while (it.MoveNext()) {
        int i = it.Current;
        list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }
}
```

Будет выведено: `123`.

В C# 4 для правильного поведения приходилось копировать значение:

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 3)) {
    int j = i;
    list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(j));
}
```

Если замыкание будет вызвано после выхода из цикла, то результат может быть неожиданным. В вашем случае это не имеет значения, так как замыкание полностью обрабатывается внутри `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Также это не имеет значения, если вы используете только C# 5 и выше.

Это один из редких случаев, когда разработчики языка решили пожертвовать обратной совместимостью во имя предсказуемого поведения.

Answer (score 3):

Это предупреждение возникает из-за наличия двух вещей в вашем коде - цикла `foreach` и анонимной функции. И цикл и анонимная функция трансформируются компилятором в несколько другой итоговый год, а в данном случае трансформация цикла оказывает влияние на трансформацию анонимной функции.

Посмотрим во что это превращается согласно спецификации (которую можно найти в папке куда установлена `Visual Studio` в подпапке `VC#\Specifications\1033`) для `c# 5.0` и выше.

Цикл `foreach` в Вашем случае превращается примерно в (параграф 8.8.4):

```
{
    var enumerator = _comps.GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            var info = (NetworkInterfaceInfo)enumerator.Current;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SpeedLabel.Content += info.NetInterface.Description + " - " + info.IncomeSpeed + "kbps\n");
        }
    }
    finally {
        enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Далее компилятор трансформирует код вызова анонимный функции (параграф 6.5.3). Так как анонимная функция использует внутри себя локальную переменную компилятору нужно превратить её во что-то имеющее большую продолжительность жизни, иначе она просто может не существовать в момент вызова анонимной функции. Поэтому компилятор создаёт примерно такой код:

```
class SpecialClass
{
  public NetworkInterfaceInfo Info;

  public void AnonimuoysFunction() 
  {
    SpeedLabel.Content += Info.NetInterface.Description + " - " + Info.IncomeSpeed + "kbps\n");
  }
}
```

После этого итоговый код цикла будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
{
    var enumerator = _comps.GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            var specialClass = new SpecialClass();
            specialClass.Info = (NetworkInterfaceInfo)enumerator.Current;
            var delegate = new Delegate(specialClass.AnonimuoysFunction);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate);
        }
    }
    finally {
        enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода - на каждую итерацию цикла создается новый экземпляр `SpecialClass`, в его поле `Info` присваивается текущее значение типа `NetworkInterfaceInfo`, а на метод `AnonimuoysFunction` этого экземпляра класса создаётся делегат, который в свою очередь передаётся в метод `Dispatcher.Invoke`. И все работает хорошо, каждый вызов делегата будет вызывать метод в уникальном экземпляре `SpecialClass`, который будет присваивать в `SpeedLabel.Content` значение зависимое от значения его поля `Info`.

---

Но, до `c#` версии 5.0 спецификация по другому описывала трансформацию цикла `foreach` компилятором. Отличие было незначительным и заключалось в том, что локальная переменная `info` объявлялась один раз, до внутреннего цикла `while`, примерно так:

```
{
    var enumerator = _comps.GetEnumerator();
    try {
        NetworkInterfaceInfo info;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            info = (NetworkInterfaceInfo)enumerator.Current;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SpeedLabel.Content += info.NetInterface.Description + " - " + info.IncomeSpeed + "kbps\n");
        }
    }
    finally {
        enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Это незначительное отличие сильно влияло на генерацию вызова анонимной функции. Сам генерируемый класс оставался таким же, но его экземпляры (точнее экземпляр) создавались иначе, что приводило к получению примерно такого кода:

```
{
    var enumerator = _comps.GetEnumerator();
    try {
       var specialClass = new SpecialClass();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            specialClass.Info = (NetworkInterfaceInfo)enumerator.Current;
            var delegate = new Delegate(specialClass.AnonimuoysFunction);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate);
        }
    }
    finally {
        enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода - для всех итераций цикла создаётся единственный экземпляр `SpecialClass`, в поле `Info` которого, на каждой итерации присваивается новое значение типа `NetworkInterfaceInfo`. Далее на метод этого экземпляра класса создаётся делегат и передаётся в `DispatchInvoke`.

В тот момент, когда функция будет вызвана нет никакой гарантии того, что в поле `Info` будет находится то значение, которое было записано на соответствующей итерации цикла. В поле `Info` на момент вызова функции будет последнее успевшее записаться на этот момент значение. Если все функции будут вызваны после выполнения цикла, то значение этого поля будет равно значению переменной присвоенной в процессе последней итерации цикла.

---

Как было верно замечено в других ответах - в данном случае `Dispatcher.Invoke` сначала выполняет полученный делегат, а только потом возвращает управление обратно. И в данном конкретном примере все действительно будет работать одинаково и в старой версии компилятора и в новой. Но, если код анонимной функции передаваемой в диспетчер со временем поменяется и будет вызывать что-нибудь асинхронно, например используя `Task.Run`, или будет вызывать какой-нибудь метод, который внутри себя вызывает что-то асинхронно, то тогда эта проблема может проявится и поведение будет отличаться в зависимости от компилятора.

Answer (score 2):

Дело тут вот в чем. В C# есть такая штука, как замыкания (и их вы тут как раз используете, захватывая в лямбду переменную цикла info). Так вот если анонимная функция захватывает переменную цикла, то есть опасность получить не то поведение, которое ожидалось. Самый известный пример такой проблемы:

```
var actions = new List<Action>();
foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 3))
{
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}

foreach(var action in actions)
{
    action();
}
```

обычная логика подсказывает, что вроде бы на консоль должно быть выведено

1
2
3

но это не так (в версиях до C# 5). 
Вы можете увидеть вы результате 
3
3
3

Связано это с тем, что лямбда-функция разворачивается за кулисами в анонимный класс, а внешние переменные, которые эта лямбда захватывает, становятся полями этого класса, то есть отныне хранятся по ссылке, а не по значению. А потому во всех случаях будет использовано значение последней итерации, то есть 3, так как ссылка во всех трех случаях будет использована одна и та же.

Стоит отметить, что это было верным вплоть до c# 4 включительно, но начиная с C# 5 это поведение было изменено - захватываемые переменные внтури циклов теперь копируются (именно так, как это подсказывает сделать решарпер), чтобы не вводить программистов в заблуждение

Answer (score 2):

Вам написали много теории, но конкретно по вашему коду ответа не было. А ответ такой:

Поскольку `Dispatcher.Invoke` не возвращает управления пока тело метода не будет выполнено, никакого различия в поведении в вашем случае наблюдаться не будет.

---

Но ваш код все еще можно улучшить, заодно избавившись от предупреждения. Что из себя представляет переменная `_comps`? Если это список, массив или любая другая неленивая коллекция, то цикл `foreach` лучше занести внутрь замыкания: `Dispatcher.Invoke` - не самая быстрая операция.

Если `_comps` - это `IEnumerable<NetworkInterfaceInfo>` или любая другая ленивая коллекция, то надо сначала сделать ей `ToList()`, а потом повторить то же самое.

```
var temp_comps = _comps.ToList();
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo info in temp_comps)
    {
        SpeedLabel.Content += info.NetInterface.Description + " - " + info.IncomeSpeed + "kbps\n");
    }    
}
```