# Заполнение массивов в отдельных потоках

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть коллекция массивов `List<int[]> mass = new List<int[]>()` состоящая из 20 (а может и более) `int[]`с общим числом элементов более 1024*20. Каждый массив нужно заполнить случайными числами. а т.к. заполнять их последовательно представляется слишком долгой операцией, я пытаюсь разделить заполнение каждого массива в отдельном потоке, но выскакивает ошибка:

> индекс за границами диапазона

Заполнение массива :

```
    static List<int[]> massives = new List<int[]>();

    static void threadfunc()
    {
        for (int j =0; j < mass; j++)
        {
             massives.Add(new int[count]);
             new Thread (delegate(){
              for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
              {
                  massives[j][i] = _rand.Next(1,101); //индекс за границами диапазона
              };
              }).Start();
        }
    }
```

Если убрать блок с `Thread(delegate)`  все заполняется правильно.

Comment: `1024 * 20` - это **очень** мало. Создание и запуск потоков - длительная операция. Поэтому в данном конкретном случае вряд ли это окупится.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov понимаю, на самом деле может быть и много больше, `1024*20` просто пример что бы отработать само создание потоков

Comment: похоже проблема в замыкании. Попробуйте перед запуском потока сохранить `j` отдельно: `int k = j;`, а затем использовать внутри делегата именно `k`

Comment: А вообще такие задачи CPU-bound лучше делать через `Parallel`, тогда среда сама создаст нужное оптимальное число потоков

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если `1024 * 20` мало то сколько поставить что бы окупилось ?

Comment: @Сергей, ни сколько. Это неправильный подход в любом случае, смотрите мой ответ

Comment: @Сергей - я обновил свой ответ. Обязательно скачайте книгу и посмотрите пример кода. Кстати, обратите внимание на размер массивов: 20 миллионов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в захвате переменной.

Нужно ввести дополнительную переменную, чтобы всё работало как надо:

```
for (int j = 0; j < mass; j++)
{
    massives.Add(new int[count]);
    int tmp = j; // <--

    new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            massives[tmp][i] = _rand.Next(1, 101); // <- tmp
        };
    }).Start();
}
```

Смотрите подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457158/184217).

Полезная ссылка: [Замыкания в языке программирования C#](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2010/04/c.html). И там смотрите ссылки на статьи Липперта.

---

#### Важно!

В данном примере кода есть критическая ошибка: так называемый [False sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).
Также рекомендую ознакомиться [RAM - не RAM, или Cache-Conscious Data Structures](http://www.1024cores.net/home/in-russian/ram---ne-ram-ili-cache-conscious-data-structures), раздел Hot/Cold Data Splitting.

Крайне рекомендую книгу Patterns for Parallel Programming, by Stephen Toub. Можно официально бесплатно [скачать](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) на сайте Майкрософт. Моя настольная книга.

В ней в разделе False sharing на странице 44 как раз рассматривается пример многопоточного заполнения массивов псевдослучайными значениями с использованием класса `Random`.

Цитата в моём переводе:

> Так как каждый вызов метода `Next` изменяет внутреннее состояние экземпляра `Random`, множество потоков будут бороться за одну и ту же линию кэша, что ведёт к серьёзному воздействию на производительность.

Решение: на каждый поток создавать свой экземпляр класса `Random`, причём таким образом, чтобы они были сильно разнесены в памяти, а следовательно, расположены в разных линиях кэша.

Comment: т.е. я пытаюсь получить из дочернего потока, ту переменную которая была инициализирована в основном и это ошибка?

Comment: @Сергей, когда вы пытаетесь воспользоваться переменной она уже имеет другое значение

Comment: А ещё проблема у ТС в многопоточном доступе без `lock`. Это по идее достаточно серьёзный баг.

Comment: @VladD, к `_rand`? А что ему от этого станет? Кроме того, что значения смогут повторяться в разных потоках?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Документация не разрешает многопоточный доступ (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx, секция «The System.Random class and thread safety».)

Answer (score 2):

В этом конкретном примере (CPU-bound) выгоднее не вручную создавать кучу потоков, а поручить создание оптимального числа потоков среде:

```
for (int j = 0; j < mass; ++j)
    massives.Add(new int[count]);

Parallel.ForEach(massives, m =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        m[i] = _rand.Next(1,101);
});
```