# Нужна помощь с потоками C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Передо мной появилась такая задача: 
Создается n потоков, в каждый поток передается значение string, и в каждом потоке оно сравнивается в условии if. Задача такова, если условие в одном из потоков верно - отключить остальные потоки и продолжить выполнять код в этом потоке. Если во всех потоках условие неверно - выполнить немного другой код. Не получается это реализовать. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Потоки вызываю таким образом:

```
var files = File.ReadAllLines(path + @"\Файл.txt", Encoding.Default); //Получаем текст из файла
for (int i = 0; i != files.Length; i++)   //Кол-во потоков = кол-ву строк в файле
{
    foreach (string line in files.ToList())
    {
        Thread mythread = new Thread(delegate () { thread(i, line); });
        mythread.Start();
    }
}
```

Работаю с методом:

```
static void thread(object obj,string line)
{

}
```

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Если все потоки не выполнили условие - выполнить определенный код
Если хоть 1 поток выполнил условие - выключаем остальные потоки, кроме этого
Не получается это реализовать

Comment: Например, можно завести переменную и каждый поток при выполнении условия пишет в нее 1, а если не выполнил - проверяет что в ней написано.

Comment: А если в нескольких потоках верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам понадобится, например, такая структура:

```
const int numberOfThreads = 3;
// для синхронизации выполнения потоков
Barrier barrier = new Barrier(numberOfThreads);
// для результатов
bool[] results = new bool[numberOfThreads];
// для синхронизации данных
object mutex = new object();

void Thread(int idx, string v)
{
    bool isGood = v.Contains(idx.ToString()); // как-то вычислили условие
    lock (mutex)
        results[idx] = isGood; // записали результат
    b.SignalAndWait(); // дождаться всех остальных потоков
    // в этой точке все результаты записаны
    bool allBad;
    lock (mutex) // читаем, все ли результаты плохие
        allBad = results.All(v => v == false);
    if (!allBad && !isGood) // если есть хорошие, но это не этот поток, отключаемся
        return;
    if (allBad)
    {
        // если ни у кого условие не выполнено, запускаем этот код
    }
    else
    {
        // иначе условие выполнено не у всех, но у нас выполнено.
        // запускаем этот код
    }
}
```

И запуск:

```
string v = "";
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    var t = new Thread(() => T(i, v));
    t.Start();
}
```

Вам, вероятно, понадобится сохранить потоки для того, чтобы дождаться окончания их работы.

---

Кстати, подумайте о том, чтобы перейти от устаревших потоков к современным `Task`'ам.

Comment: Появилась ошибка..   
var files = File.ReadAllLines(path + @"\Настройки функций.ini", Encoding.Default);  
                numberOfThreads = files.Length;
                barrier = new Barrier(numberOfThreads);
                results =new bool[numberOfThreads];
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
                    {
                        var t = new Thread(() => Thread(i, files[i]));
                        t.Start();
                    }

Comment: @Varagian: А какая ошибка?

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @Varagian: А в какой строчке конкретно? И чему равны значения переменных в этой строчке?

Comment: @Varagian: Да, в вашем коде очевидная ошибка. Смотрите сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677965/10105

Comment: Спасибо, понял свою ошибку. Но теперь появилась еще одна проблема с выполнением кода в потоке. VladD, можно с вами где-нибудь связаться, чтобы там обсудить проблему?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68753/discussion-between-varagian-and-vladd).