# Вложенные Parallel.For

Tags: c#, многопоточность, parallel

В принципе, я более менее понял суть того, чтобы данные в потоках не пересекались, но что делать, если у меня есть в потоке свои вложенные потоки, как быть здесь?

```
 Parallel.For(5, 15, TF => 
        {
            Bars = CompressTo(BarsStart, TF);
            int countBars = Bars.Count;
            profitSave = 0;

            Parallel.For(0, 10000, j =>
            {
                int fastPeriod = rnd.Next(10, 100);
                int slowPeriod = rnd.Next(fastPeriod, 300);
                List<double> Fast = iMa.MA.SMA(Bars, fastPeriod);
                List<double> Slow = iMa.MA.SMA(Bars, slowPeriod);

                int i = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < countBars - 1; i++)
                {
                    // Здесь я использую Fast, Slow,Bars и рассчитываю profit
                }


                lock (locker)
                    if (profit > profitSave)
                        profitSave = profit;
            });
        });
```

Если сделать 1 поток, только вложенный, всё прекрасно, но если я хочу использовать 2 потока, то тут пересекаются данные, как можно решить проблему? Изменяется только `Bars` - `Fast` - `Slow`. Получается, в глобальном цикле инициализируется `Bars`, а во вложенном цикле на основе Bars инициализируются `Fast` и `Slow`. Ошибка в том, что `Fast` и `Slow` бывают инициализируются не от своего созданного `Bars`, а от списка из другого потока, а в главном цикле у каждого `Bars` разное число элементов и поэтому в просто цикле `for` мы ловим исключение `OutOfRange`.

Comment: Класс `Random` не потокобезопасный. Неправильно его так использовать. И вообще, нужен ли внутренний `Parallel.For`? Первый и так создаст потоков больше, чем ядер в системе (ну, в большинстве нынешних средних систем).

Comment: Насчёт рандома, см. раздел "Важно" в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677965/184217).

Answer (score 0):

> как можно решить проблему?

Дочитав до конца документацию.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299(v=vs.110).aspx

Используйте перегруженный вариант:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult Parallel.For<TLocal>(
    int fromInclusive,
    int toExclusive,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<int, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

подавая/возвращая `Bars` в качестве `TLocal`.